# useTransition mounts new object instantly

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I am trying to figure out how to utilise `useTransition` for page transitions (simple opacity change where first page fades out and new one fades in).

So far I have this small demo going https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-knuth-xe8e0?file=/src/App.js
it somewhat works, but weirdly. When transition starts new page is mounted instantly while old one starts animating. This causes various layout issues and is not behaviour I am after. Is it possible to have first element fade out and only then mount and fade in second element?

Code associated to demo

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useTransition, a } from "react-spring";

export default function App() {
  const [initial, setInitial] = useState(true);
  const transition = useTransition(initial, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {transition((style, initial) => {
        return initial ? (
          <a.h1 style={style}>Hello Initial</a.h1>
        ) : (
          <a.h1 style={style}>Hello Secondary</a.h1>
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={() => setInitial(prev => !prev)}>Change Page</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can delay the start of the transition by waiting for the leave animation to complete.

```
const sleep = t => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t));

...

const transition = useTransition(initial, {
  from: { position: "absolute", opacity: 0 },
  enter: i => async next => {
    await sleep(1000);
    await next({ opacity: 1 });
  },
  leave: { opacity: 0 }
});
```

This delays the animation also for the very first time it is run. You can have a ref to keep track of whether the component has been rendered before or if it is its first time rendering, then you can skip `sleep` call if it's the first render.

OR

You can just simply provide `trail` config

```
const transition = useTransition(initial, {
    from: { position: "absolute", opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    trail: 300
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: absolute` and then you need to set the right position with css.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useTransition, a } from "react-spring";

export default function App() {
  const [initial, setInitial] = useState(true);
  const transition = useTransition(initial, {
    from: { position: 'absolute', opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {transition((style, initial) => {
        return initial ? (
          <a.h1 style={style}>Hello Initial</a.h1>
        ) : (
          <a.h1 style={style}>Hello Secondary</a.h1>
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={() => setInitial(prev => !prev)}>Change Page</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Alright, this solves layout issue, but still starts animation right away instead of waiting for previous one to complete. Is it possible to achieve this with transitions in react-spring, or would it require custom logic with normal useSpring where children are cached or something like that?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-wind-2gklv I added `position: "absolute"` and it works fine. @Ilja